# access settings from whole jquery component

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to develop a jquery component for dialog modals and i dont know how to access the settings from all component functions. I need to access `settings.zIndex` from open function and it seems to not work.

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {

        init: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                bgClass: "fancy-dialog-bg",
                bgShow: null,
                zIndex: 100,
                show: null
            };
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var obj = $(this).hide().css("position", "fixed").css("z-index", settings.zIndex).css("left", "300px").css("top", "200px");
            });

        },

        open: function() {
                    // alert(settings.zIndex); not working
            var tes = $("<div></div>").css("backgroundColor", "#f00").css("position", "fixed").css("z-index", "99").css("width", "50%").css("height", "100%").css("left", "0").css("top", "0");
            $('body').append(tes);
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.show();

        },

        close: function() {

            var obj = $(this);
            $("#fancy-dialog-bg-" + obj.attr('id')).remove();
            obj.hide();

        }

    };

    $.fn.fancyDialog = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist.');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

to this:

```
 this.settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

Then, settings will be a property of your methods object which you can access via:

```
 methods.settings
```

Comment: Yeah, that's because of the way you're dispatching the methods.  You're calling the methods with `this` as the jQuery object not the `methods` object where the settings are stored.  So, if you don't pass the `methods` object in any way and that's where the settings are stored, bingo you can't access them.  I have to run this moment.  You will have to change the design of how you call the methods or how you store the settings.

Comment: well i copyed this template from jquery.com.. im still a beginner in making a component :) do you happen to know a good template for building components like the one that i am trying to develop ? ty

Comment: Since you only have one of these `methods` objects, it looks like (if you make the first change I recommended), you can access the settings via `methods.settings`.  Probably, the example youcopied expects to use settings for the single method that is being executed, not as global settings that must be stored in a globally accessible location.